# Is there a Jest function, to disallow any other function calls than expected?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I know that you can mock out and spy on function calls inside a function, e.g. with jest.spyOn and jest.fn() ... .toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) etc. In Spock framework testing, you can end your unit test with a:

0 * _                           // don't allow any other interaction

Is there a way to achieve this via Jest?

Example:

```js
export default class Service {

    public startAllWorkers(): void {
        const processClient: ProcessClient = new ProcessClient();
        const processMonitor: ProcessMonitor = new ProcessMonitor();
        const defaultValue: number = 10;

        processClient.runClient(defaultValue);
        processMonitor.runMonitor('pling')
    }

}
```

```js
describe('Service test', () => {

    let service: Service;

    beforeEach(() => {
        service = new Service();
        ProcessClient.prototype.runClient = jest.fn()
        ProcessMonitor.prototype.runMonitor = jest.fn()
    });

    it('should only call specific methods', () => {
        const spyService = jest.spyOn(service, 'startAllWorkers');

        service.startAllWorkers();

        expect(spyService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(ProcessClient.prototype.runClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(ProcessMonitor.prototype.runMonitor).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        // expect no other interactions inside service method
    });

})
```

Comment: Please, fix the formatting and probably improve the example with something more meaningful, 0 * _ symbols don't make much sense for anybody who isn't familiar with Spock.

Answer (score 1):

Jest spy functionality is relatively modest. `toBeCalledWith` assertion allows to check if one of calls was made with specified arguments.

More specific calls need to be asserted explicitly:

```
// fn('foo', 1);
// fn('bar', 2);
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledTimes(2); // redundant but provides human readable output
expect(mockFn.mock.calls).toEqual([
  ['foo', 1]
  ['bar', expect.any(Number)]
]);
```

In case a function isn't called consecutively, a spy can be shortly asserted to not allow unexpected calls:

```
// fn('foo', 1);
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledWith('foo', 1);
mockFn.mockClear();
...
// fn('bar', 2);
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledWith('bar', 2);
mockFn.mockClear();
...
expect(mockFn).not.toBeCalled();
```

Alternatively, a smart spy can be responsible for the implementation and expected usage:

```
mockFn.mockImplementation((...args) => {
  // first call
  if (mockFn.mock.calls.length === 1) {
    expect(args).toEqual(...);
    return ...;
  }

  // second call
  if (mockFn.mock.calls.length === 2) {
    expect(args).toEqual(...);
    return ...;
  }

  // no more calls
  expect(mockFn.mock.calls.length).not.toBe(3);
});
```

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, thanks for this detailed answer. I like the last implementation, but I am wondering if this can be used to function calls inside your mockFn? I have put together an example in inital question.

Comment: I see. I believe no, at least without hacking into Jest implementation of spies. The test you wrote is usually enough to test the method. At this point any unexpected interactions can be tracked with test coverage, these lines will be marked as uncovered. Weak spots in this test is that you use real ProcessClient and ProcessMonitor, so tested unit can freely interact with them besides mocked methods, entire classes should be mocked instead. Also `ProcessClient.prototype.runClient =` should never be used in Jest, original implementation is lost for the entire suite, use `jest.spyOn`.